# AnyLogic: How do I get rid of agents connected to GIS Points when the delivery was finished?

Tags: anylogic

I have 3 vehicles that start from a distribution center and are supposed to deliver packages to 5 destinations. Each vehicle can only carry one package at a time. So after the first delivery, they
drive back to the dc and get another package and so on. I have created a product order as agent so the destinations can order a package. Every destination is supposed to order a single time.

And now here is the problem: Im using an event as trigger for the orders. Its a timeout that occurs once.
When i run the programm im getting a null error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzv4l.png)

Im guessing this is because there are not enough vehicles to serve all orders.
Now I changed the code in the event to
[Code of the event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfmPT.png)

So only when the null error doesnt occur the orders get sent.

**Update:** So I checked with traceln if orders get sent and recieved by trucks. [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QZs1.jpg)

The last two orders were sent but not recieved. (Cause there is no truck available at that time). When they come back from the first delivery, they should check if there are more orders active and do a second tour if necessary.

It feels like there is some code missing but I dont know where.
[Vehicle logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp9NZ.png)

Comment: Try figuring out what happens to the trucks when no more orders are being accepted. Use `traceln`, pause the model and check the truck state charts "live"... There is no obvious problem here so it is likely some logic error you are having somewhere

Comment: Hey, Benjamin. Thanks for your help. I wrote an update to my question above.

Comment: "When they come back from the first delivery, they should check if there are more orders active and do a second tour if necessary. "

Well, do they? If not, make them do it. If you don't know how, check the tutorial here, it covers this and more: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/gis/index.html#supply-chain-gis-model

Comment: I created my program based on your linked guide. My approach and therefore my problem is a bit different. In the guide the "retailers" request products every day. When trucks come back they get new request eventually. In my case they would need to deliver the "old" requests. I would probably need to add a arraylist to store the messages. Since im a beginner at coding I just delete the served customer with order.Customer.deleteSelf(); after the truck started driving to the customer. Then im able to resend messages for the last two stops. Not the best approach but it works I guess.

Comment: All correct. You need to store those (better use a LinkedList actually for this) and then get your trucks to "pick off" one by one